# What can I do to detect changes to my computer from a program?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to detect which changes a program makes to your computer? Like new files created, registry changes, anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.
>
> [image]

Comment: Awesome.. That more than fits the description of exactly what I was looking for :D Thanks

Comment: @Tom Wijsman - Can I assume this would be helpful for debugging if a malicious script had (for example) disabled all the system Services?

Comment: @DaveRook - You might want to look at Mark Russinovich's blog posts, where he shows examples of these: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963890.aspx

Comment: @DaveRook: Yes, it does, you'll see the process that runs the script change the start type of some services in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, [winpooch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpooch/) used to do this, but this stopped working with XP SP2.

Trackwininstall would work for this in theory - the website's in german but they link to a [google translated english version](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.withopf.com/tools/trackwinstall/&langpair=de%7Cen), I'm away from my test systems so I haven't tried it out yet

Some uninstallers may do this as part of the uninstall process - revo uninstaller's [professional version](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_uninstall_features.html) may do this as part of its real time installation manager.

You could also use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), as Tom suggested to monitor filesystem changes and registry changes - this is the lowest level, generic way to do this, but may need you to set up filters as needed.
I referenced [this thread](http://forum.sysinternals.com/procmon-monitor-installation-program_topic13423.html) for this answer, and it might be useful for your own reference.